# how to show only chennai map in javascript using googlemap api 3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm creating javascript app using Google map Api 3. Can anyone suggest me how to show google map of chennai only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using custom tiles - as per this example [texus custom tile](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_texas.html)